# High performance and secure network mounts for linux

Tags: file-transfer, nas

I have a NAS I want to network mount to my computer to be used over the LAN and over the internet. I need the connection to be encrypted so I tried SFTP but found the transfer speed to be really slow (about 30Mbit/s with a 1Gbit connection). This seems to be [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849240/why-when-i-transfer-a-file-through-sftp-it-takes-longer-than-ftp). I am currently looking for alternatives that would fit these requirements.

Are there any linux tools that would allow me to network mount drives at a high speed while also keeping everything encrypted?

Comment: nfs through vpn.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sshfs, however this uses sftp as its underlaying protocol, yet combine this with ssh's compression feature and you might get the speed you want.